# INSERT INTO giving error in Ucanaccess

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, ucanaccess

I am trying to insert a row into a table (userGames), using [Ucanaccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/), and, when executing the statement, am recieving the following error:

```
Feb 10, 2015 8:29:02 PM db.Connect update
SEVERE: null
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: unknown token: 
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.execute(UcanaccessStatement.java:145)
at db.Connect.update(Connect.java:42)
at db.GameScanner.searchGames(GameScanner.java:99)
at db.GameScanner.<init>(GameScanner.java:91)
at db.WelcomeGUI.scanButtonActionPerformed(WelcomeGUI.java:143)
at db.WelcomeGUI.access$000(WelcomeGUI.java:24)
at db.WelcomeGUI$1.actionPerformed(WelcomeGUI.java:105)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unknown token: 
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.Execute.executeWrapped(Execute.java:62)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.AbstractExecute.executeBase(AbstractExecute.java:138)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.Execute.execute(Execute.java:52)
at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.execute(UcanaccessStatement.java:143)
... 42 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unknown token: 
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.read(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readColumnOrFunctionExpression(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleValueExpressionPrimary(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesValueExpressionPrimary(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesPrimary(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesFactor(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesTerm(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesCommonValueExpression(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadValueExpression(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadRowElementList(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesValueExpressionPrimary(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesPrimary(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesFactor(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesTerm(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesCommonValueExpression(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadValueExpressionOrNull(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadValueExpressionWithContext(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readRow(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadContextuallyTypedTable(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDML.compileInsertStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
... 48 more
```

In my connect class, i have the following:

```
private Connection conn;

public Connect(String filepath) {
    try {
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + filepath + ";");
        System.out.println("Connection successful");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and the update/insert method:

```
public boolean update(String sql) {
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        result = stmt.execute(sql);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Connect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am sending the following SQL statement to the update method:

```
"INSERT INTO userGames (userID,gameID) VALUES ("+users[id]+","+games[i]+")"
```

I have no idea what an "unknown token" is, or what I should do to rectify the error.

I have read the guide for Ucanaccess, and they do the same thing as I am doing, as far as I can see. Both .execute and .executeUpdate throw this error, and I do not know what to do.

Thanks for any help

Riccorbypro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because you have pasted strings into your SQL, without enclosing them in `' '` marks, so the SQL has some words in it that the database doesn't know how to interpret.

You should be using a `PreparedStatement`, and setting `users[id]` and `games[i]` to parameters within the `PreparedStatement`.  This is explained fully in [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 0):

What David Wallace said .....

`"INSERT INTO userGames (userID,gameID) VALUES ('"+users[id]+'",'"+games[i]+"')"`

The easiest way to debug this is to just print your SQL statement before you execute it.

But you really should use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: Whatever you do, do NOT get into the habit of building up SQL by concatenating strings in this way.  It's only a matter of time before you create an SQL injection vulnerability.  Learn the correct way of doing it from the start.  Use a `PreparedStatement`.